# phpseclib file not found when file DOES exist

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I have been using phpseclib for 2 years without a flaw and all the sudden the sftp "get()" function started to give me NET_SFTP_STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE: File not found.

I have a loop that looks like this:

```
foreach ($sftp->rawlist() as $filename => $details) {
    //  open only files no directories
    if ($details['type'] == 1) {
        //  reads file to string
        $sftp_data[$filename] .= $sftp->get($filename);
        $files_counter++;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, the rawlist() function loops through the file but the problem occurs when the script get to $sftp->get($filename) function.

The permission to the folder have not changed and the sftp user has full access to folder and files.

I have already try

define('NET_SFTP_LOGGING', NET_SFTP_LOG_COMPLEX);

for debugging but that didn't shed any lights to the issue.

Here is the $sftp->getSFTPLog() output:

```
[0] => -> NET_SFTP_INIT (0.0008s)
[1] => <- NET_SFTP_VERSION (0.0009s)
[2] => -> NET_SFTP_REALPATH (0.0004s)
[3] => <- NET_SFTP_NAME (0.001s)
[4] => -> NET_SFTP_REALPATH (0.0005s)
[5] => <- NET_SFTP_NAME (0.001s)
[6] => -> NET_SFTP_OPENDIR (0.0005s)
[7] => <- NET_SFTP_HANDLE (0.0018s)
[8] => -> NET_SFTP_CLOSE (0.0005s)
[9] => <- NET_SFTP_STATUS (0.0009s)
[10] => -> NET_SFTP_OPENDIR (0.0005s)
[11] => <- NET_SFTP_HANDLE (0.0017s)
[12] => -> NET_SFTP_READDIR (0.0004s)
[13] => <- NET_SFTP_NAME (0.001s)
[14] => -> NET_SFTP_READDIR (0.0004s)
[15] => <- NET_SFTP_STATUS (0.0009s)
[16] => -> NET_SFTP_CLOSE (0.0004s)
[17] => <- NET_SFTP_STATUS (0.001s)
[18] => -> NET_SFTP_OPEN (0.0005s)
[19] => <- NET_SFTP_STATUS (0.001s)
[20] => -> NET_SFTP_OPENDIR (0.0005s)
[21] => <- NET_SFTP_HANDLE (0.0017s)
[22] => -> NET_SFTP_READDIR (0.0004s)
[23] => <- NET_SFTP_NAME (0.0011s)
[24] => -> NET_SFTP_READDIR (0.0004s)
[25] => <- NET_SFTP_STATUS (0.001s)
[26] => -> NET_SFTP_CLOSE (0.0004s)
[27] => <- NET_SFTP_STATUS (0.0009s)
[28] => -> NET_SFTP_OPEN (0.0005s)
[29] => <- NET_SFTP_STATUS (0.0009s)
[30] => -> NET_SFTP_OPEN (0.0002s)
[31] => <- NET_SFTP_STATUS (0.0009s)
```

I am open to suggestions.

Comment: What does the `$filename` value look like (please give few examples). What does `sftp->getSFTPLog()` return anyway?

Comment: Yah - I second Martin's response. Seeing the logs would be helpful. Also, the SSH logs might be useful as well (`define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);`)

Comment: the $filename looks something like "File_2015_01_27.txt"

Comment: $sftp->getSFTPErrors() returns NET_SFTP_STATUS_NO_SUCH_FILE: File not found

Comment: $sftp->getSFTPLog() returns an array. Is too long so I will post it above.

Comment: Seeing the full packets would be useful - not just the headers. If you feel they're too large to post on stackoverflow you can put them on pastebin.com and post a link to that. Also, I had asked for the SSH2 logs as well..